# Where can I find delay/cancelation statistics for a given airline route?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, cancellations, delays

My flight got canceled yesterday and I am currently waiting for the delayed next flight.

Is there any website that keeps records of airlines being delayed/canceled? I would like to know my chances. I did find some sites through google (flightaware, flightstats), but they focus on us flights only and I am currently in the azores.

Comment: Seasons can also affect things - eg an early morning flight could be delayed by fog lots at one time of the year, but not others. Ice/snow tend can be an issue in winter, but not summer!

Comment: I laughed out loud as I came here after being delayed 7 hours thanks to Azores Airlines

Answer (score 18):

You can't predict the future, but you can always get a good expectation out of historical data. Hence, I suggest [flightstats.com](https://www.flightstats.com/), it lets you know the on time performance for an airline and/or a specific flight for that airline based on real historical data for a given time, something like:

[image: delta stats]

Update:

sample flight link : https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-ontime-performance-rating/AI/101/

Then, you can simply have a good estimate of the chance of not arriving on time.

Comment: That is indeed very useful! Unfortunately, it seems that Ryanair is not included. Any idea of alternative sites that also include Ryanair?

Answer (score 4):

One such site is http://www.flightaware.com - type in the airline and the flight number into the "Airline Flight Tracker" box on the left-hand side of the page and press enter.

On the result page, your information is in the section "Activity log". Note that on  different days, the planned departure and arrival times for your flight may be different, so consider looking through all of the entries by hand (you can click on the dates for each of the entries to see details). Also, some airlines have multiple routes with the same flight number, so you also have to check the departure/arrival airports.

Comment: "Average Delay: More than 1 hour" disappointing use of math there..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a subscription to ExpertFlyer, it provides some statistics on past flights based on the last sixty or so days, on the **Travel Information Search** page.

[image: BA 245 reliability.]

It even works in the Azores.

[image: S4 120 reliability.]

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sites which collect and will show you stats on various airlines performance. In this case, the following:

http://www.flightstats.com/ or http://www.flightstats.co.uk/ will help you.

Good luck!

Comment: These give real time data, but not historical or agregated data. (At least I couldn't find it).

Answer (score 1):

FlightRadar24 airplane tracking site has this info, free access allows going back 10-ish days statistics.

https://www.flightradar24.com/data

Answer (score 1):

**FlightEra** shows graphs of On Time Performance and Average Delay of specific flights on a monthly and yearly basis.

sample : https://www.flightera.net/delays/Air+India/AI101

screenshot:

[image: AI 101 monthly and yearly graph]

Tickets.pl shows Punctuality rating for flights by an airline.

*Statistics on Tickets.pl are provided by FlightStats, Inc.

sample: https://tickets.pl/en/avia/rating/AI/punctuality