# Statistics on how often certain flights are cancelled

Tags: air-travel, vietnam, cancellations, statistics

Is there a reliable way of finding statistics on how often certain airlines cancel flights or certain routes get cancelled? Bonus points if that varies depending on the season.

I'm planning a trip in Southeast Asia, looking to take the Da Nang - Can Tho flight, which is only offered by Vietjet (VJC 702) and not very frequently. If that flight is cancelled, it will cramp the rest of the vacation, but the only alternative is flying to Ho Chi Minh and taking a many-hour bus ride, which is something I'd definitely want to avoid if not absolutely necessary.

From [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19312/where-can-i-find-delay-cancelation-statistics-for-a-given-airline-route) I checked flightstats.com, but they don't have any data for the route I'm interested. The main reason I'm worried about this specific route is that I read customer reviews online complaining about Vietjet's cancellations, but naturally that doesn't provide enough information to show whether it's actually a significant risk.

Answer (score 3):

Flightaware is another service like flightstats

your flight...

http://flightaware.com/live/flight/VJC702

http://flightaware.com/live/flight/VJC702/history

if you register, you get more history.

Comment: There is not even one row showing whether the flight even happened or not.

Comment: What do you mean?  http://flightaware.com/live/flight/VJC702/history  ALL OF THOSE HAPPENED.  It gives you the departure / arrival times!  Note that if it was cancelled, IT SAYS "CANCELLED" in large red letters!